# Are there .NET bindings for Autodesk's FBX SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, importing, fbx

I'm writing a tool in C# that needs to open FBX files (and the XNA content pipeline isn't a suitable solution). I note that Autodesk only provides it's FBX SDK as a C++ class library.

Before I write it myself I thought I'd ask if anyone knows of existing .NET bindings for this SDK?

Comment: Did you ever get around to implementing this yourself?

Comment: No. I changed jobs and so the project I was going to use it for never came to anything.

Comment: Well xna has wrapper inside it, so you can "look" how they did it :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I don't think there are any -- I've never stumbled across them, at least. There's definitely a niche there if you can write a C# wrapper that can be distributed (not sure what the FBX SDK license terms are, though, they may make that cumbersome).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Max.NET](http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/plugins/max-net).

> Max.NET is a .NET CLR wrapper for 3d Studio Max's (3dsmax) software development kit (SDK). It allows developers to write tools for 3dsmax in a managed and reflective environment using any of the common .NET languages such as C#, VB.net, J#, and C++/CLI. Moreover it provides access to all of the classes and their members accessible to normal unmanaged SDK.

According to Scriptspot, the homepage link for Max.NET is [here](http://ephere.com/autodesk/max/), so use that if the above link goes dead.

Comment: This looks nifty, but it sounds like it's geared for writing extensions to Max itself, not a wrapper for the FBX SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: I maintain [FbxSharp](https://github.com/izrik/FbxSharp), A pure C# library for loading FBX files. It's not a wrapper, though. It's an attempt to re-implement the functionality of the FBX SDK in pure C#, so a consumer wouldn't have to bother with interop. At present it's workable, but only covers a subset of the features and versions of the FBX SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this for a long time..
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=fbx

Sooner or later this will be too old to use. 
It only works writes 2009 (6100) version of FBX but its a built DLL ready to use.
It reads 2015 with no problems.
Just put it in your projects directory and make sure its being copied to the output location. Also.. Make sure you include it with any setup projects!
Here's a link to the DLL and A lot of code. Its in VB.net but can easily be converted to C#.
This code is from a App I wrote and has a lot of subs and functions you will never need. It does show how to build instanced objects and materials and also non-instanced.
http://tnmshouse.com/FBX_Wrapper/

Why am I doing this? Because its very hard to get any help with FBX and how to work with it. This code is sloppy but has a lot you can use. It has NOTHING about animations although the FBX wrapper apparently can work with them.